# Ошибка функции sort()

Tags: c++, visual-studio

В Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, V 16.3.2 при попытке компиляции   кода С++ с участием функции sort() получаю квест:

```
// ConsoleApplication3.cpp : Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<double> temps;
    for (double temp; cin >> temp;)
        temps.push_back(temp);
    sort(temps[0], temps[1]);
}
```

```
1>------ Сборка начата: проект: ConsoleApplication3, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------
1>ConsoleApplication3.cpp
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\algorithm(3466,5): error C2672: "_Sort_unchecked": не найдена соответствующая перегруженная функция
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\algorithm(3471): message : выполняется компиляция ссылки на экземпляр шаблон функции "void std::sort<_RanIt,std::less<void>>(const _RanIt,const _RanIt,_Pr)"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\algorithm(3471): message :         with
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\algorithm(3471): message :         [
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\algorithm(3471): message :             _RanIt=double,
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\algorithm(3471): message :             _Pr=std::less<void>
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\algorithm(3471): message :         ]
1>C:\Users\...\source\repos\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3.cpp(15): message : выполняется компиляция ссылки на экземпляр шаблон функции "void std::sort<_Ty>(const _RanIt,const _RanIt)"
1>C:\Users\...\source\repos\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3.cpp(15): message :         with
1>C:\Users\...\source\repos\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3.cpp(15): message :         [
1>C:\Users\...\source\repos\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3.cpp(15): message :             _Ty=double,
1>C:\Users\...\source\repos\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3.cpp(15): message :             _RanIt=double
1>C:\Users\...\source\repos\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3.cpp(15): message :         ]
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\algorithm(3466,1): error C2893: Сбой при специализации функции-шаблона "void std::_Sort_unchecked(_RanIt,_RanIt,iterator_traits<_Iter>::difference_type,_Pr)".
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\algorithm(3436): message : см. объявление "std::_Sort_unchecked"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\algorithm(3466,1): message : Со следующими аргументами шаблона:
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\algorithm(3466,1): message : "_RanIt=_Iter"
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\algorithm(3466,1): message : "_Pr=_Fn"
1>Сборка проекта "ConsoleApplication3.vcxproj" завершена с ошибкой.
========== Сборка: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

Что тут не так? Спасибо за любой совет.

Comment: sort принимает диапазон, а значит нужно передать или указатели или итераторы, а не элементы массива или другие обьекты, которые не имеют свойства итераторов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sort(temps.begin(), temps.end());
```

или

```
sort(begin(temps), end(temps));
```

Что вы хотели добиться записью

```
sort(temps[0], temps[1]);
```

категорически не понимаю...

Comment: Harry, наверное ТС хочет сортировать вставками

Comment: Изначально было sort(temps) в соответствии с первоисточником (B.Stroustrup "Programming. Principles and Practice Using C++"). Компиляция указала на ошибку что функция должна иметь два аргумента, это и привело к такому виду. Спасибо за ответ, теперь возникает вопрос - стоит ли использовать книгу в дальнейшем?

Comment: Стоп-стоп, дайте конкретную ссылку на книгу - раздел, например. Или страницу, если второе издание - у меня она есть, хотелось бы посмотреть, думаю, вы в чем-то не разобрались...

Comment: да, вы можете написать свою функцию  void  sort(Cont c) {  std::sort(std::begin(c),  std::end(c)); }  а потом вызвать  sort(temps)

Comment: ISBN 978-5-8459-1949-6 (рус). Глава 4, 4.6 Вектор стр. 163

Comment: Отлично, там показано использование `sort(temps)`, но никак не `sort(temps[0],temps[1])`. Это для начала. Далее, вероятно, вы не очень внимательно читали начало, либо Страуструп нее очень внятно указал этот момент - что весь код в его книге использует `#include "std_lib_facilities.h"` - его специально разработанный для данной книги заголовочный файл `"std_lib_facilities.h"` - в котором он, в частности, дает перегрузку функции `sort`, принимающую вектор. Это - *не* стандартная функция С++. Скачайте этот файл с сайта Страуструпа, подключите - и `sort(temps)` у вас отлично заработает.

Comment: `// ConsoleApplication3.cpp : Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 //#include <iostream> //#include <string> //#include <vector> //#include <algorithm> //#include <cmath> //using namespace std; //inline void keep_window_open() { char ch; cin >> ch; } #include "std_lib_facilities.h" int main() { vector<double> temps; for (double temp; cin >> temp;) { temps.push_back(temp); } sort(temps); }` во 2-й главе, стр. 94 сказано что можно заменить этот файл на стандартные директивы, но не суть... Все равно не работает:

Comment: `1>------ Сборка начата: проект: ConsoleApplication3, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------
1>ConsoleApplication3.cpp
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.23.28105\include\hash_map(18,1): fatal error C1189: #error:  <hash_map> is deprecated and will be REMOVED. Please use <unordered_map>. You can define _SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS to acknowledge that you have received this warning.
1>Сборка проекта "ConsoleApplication3.vcxproj" завершена с ошибкой.
========== Сборка: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========`

Comment: Знаете, наверное, и в самом деле отложите эту книгу и возьмите что-то типа "С++ для чайников" - в ваших жалобах видно нежелание *разбираться*, что к чему, а просто получить все готовенькое... Компилятор ясно сказал, что его не устраивает, и как именно решить проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите вставить элементы так, чтобы вектор оказался отсортированным, то можете: с самого начала заполнения вставить на последнем месте нужный элемент. Для этого есть стандартный альгоритм:

```
vector<double> temps;   
for (double temp; cin >> temp;) {
    temps.push_back(temp);
    std::nth_element(temps.begin(), temps.end() - 1, temps.end());
}
```